# Cypher query to find shortest partial paths and aggregate the result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find the minimum checkpoints that were traversed between the nodes for each person. There are multiple paths that can be traversed by each person.

Example:

```
CREATE
  (:person {id: 0}),
  (:person {id: 1})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1'})-[:rel2]->(:chkpt2 {id: '2'}),

  (:person {id: 2})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1_1'}),
  (:person {id: 2})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1_2'})-[:rel2]->(:chkpt2 {id: '2_1'}),
  (:person {id: 2})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1_3'})-[:rel2]->(:chkpt2 {id: '2_2'})-[:rel3]->(:chkpt3 {id: '3_1'}),

  (:person {id: 3})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1_4'})-[:rel2]->(:chkpt2 {id: '2_3'})-[:rel3]->(:chkpt3 {id: '3_2'}),
  (:person {id: 3})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1_5'})-[:rel2]->(:chkpt2 {id: '2_4'})-[:rel3]->(:chkpt3 {id: '3_3'}),
  (:person {id: 3})-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1 {id: '1_6'})-[:rel2]->(:chkpt2 {id: '2_5'})-[:rel3]->(:chkpt3 {id: '3_4'})
```

Currently, I am using the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause and running multiple queries as follows:

```
MATCH (p:person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:rel1]-(cp1:chkpt1)
WITH p, cp1
WHERE cp1 IS NULL
RETURN p.id
```

Returns: person0

Then I run a separate query to find all the persons that didn't make it to the next checkpoint.

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:rel1]-(cp1:chkpt1)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cp1)-[:rel2]-(cp2:chkpt2)
WITH p, cp1, cp2
WHERE cp2 IS NULL
RETURN DISTINCT p.id, cp1.id
```

Returns: person2

Similarly for the next checkpoint.

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:rel1]-(cp1:chkpt1)-[:rel2]-(cp2:chkpt2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (cp2)-[:rel3]-(cp3:chkpt3)
WITH p, cp1, cp2, cp3
WHERE cp3 IS NULL
RETURN DISTINCT p.id, cp1.id, cp2.id
```

Returns: person1 and person2

I want to return only person1 as person2 missed previous traversals.

```
MATCH (p:person)-[:rel1]-(cp1:chkpt1)-[:rel2]-(cp2:chkpt2)-[:rel3]-(cp3:chkpt3)
RETURN DISTINCT p.id, cp1.id, cp2.id
```

Returns: person2 and person3

However, I want to only return person3 as person2 did not make it to chkpt3 and chkpt2.

I need to not include the persons that have already been excluded because they did not make it to the previous checkpoint on another traversal.

Example:

- person1 should only show up that they did not make it to chkpt1.
- person2 should only show up that they did not make it to chkpt3.
- person3 shows up in chkpt3 as they completed all the paths to the final chkpt3.

I would like to summarize the counts of the persons that made it to a certain checkpoint. As there could be multiple persons that made it to the shortest checkpoint.

I also tried to combine all queries with multiple `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses but that slows down a lot when the number of nodes increases.

There will be 100.000 to a million total nodes. The actual traversal will only involve 1000s of nodes as the persons will be filtered based on some value.

Comment: Are these traces (paths) stored separately in the graph? For example, do you create two nodes for person1? (As your first query returns person1, I believe this is the case.)

Comment: Each person will be a single node with multiple edges.

Comment: Do you have a fixed (small) amount of checkpoints or is this also subject to change?

Comment: This is important b/c if there are a lot of checkpoints, it's better to use a generic label (e.g. `:Checkpoint`) and an attribute (e.g. `step`). Also, I added a figure and made some changes in your example -- please double check.

Comment: @JeffNewbie In the DB you provided, every person has 1 edge. (And I can't make sense of the schema) If you change your schema to use one set of checkpoints (connected by some `:Next` relation) and each person as a `:Reached` relation to each checkpoint they made it to, your query could just be `MATCH (person:person) OPTIONAL MATCH (person)-[:REACHED]->(cp:chkpt) RETURN person, COUNT(cp) as checkpoints ORDER BY checkpoints` (filtered as needed. Not really sure what you actually want as the final result) Here is an [example](http://console.neo4j.org/r/hpvhyx) of what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I want to only return person3 as person2 did not make it to chkpt3 and chkpt2.

How about this query? It counts the number of traversals a person is involved in and checks whether they made it to checkpoint 3 in all traversals.

```
MATCH (p:person)-[r]-()
WITH p, count(r) AS allTraversals
MATCH (p)-[:rel1]-(cp1:chkpt1)-[:rel2]-(cp2:chkpt2)-[:rel3]-(cp3:chkpt3)
WITH p, allTraversals, count(cp3) AS cp3s
WHERE allTraversals = cp3s
RETURN p
```

(Note: this will not work for `person0`.)

Additionally, a couple of observations:

(1.) You can use the [`WHERE NOT <pattern>`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/clauses/where/#filter-on-patterns-using-not) construct to formulate negative conditions in a more succinct way.

```
MATCH (p:person)
WHERE NOT (p:person)-[:rel1]->(:chkpt1)
RETURN p
```

(2.) If it's possible, you might consider reviewing your data model and store persons and checkpoints as a single node and add the paths between them. This is a more graph-like representation and should help in formulating efficient queries.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated the question.
(1) I will try that
(3) As I am looking for the earliest checkpoint that was reached, therefore person 1 is indicated as not reaching chkpt1. 
For person 2 I updated the question to clarify.
I am looking to identify how many persons made it to all the chkpts, if they did not then which ckhpt was the minimum they reached.